# Trying to calculate ASCII code sum of my "sir" (string) class

Tags: c++, string, class, sum, ascii

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>


using namespace std;

class sir{
  int lung; //sir lenght
  char* sirul;  //pointer to the first character form sir
  public:
    sir(const char*);//constructor,for test
    ~sir();// destructor
    char operator[](int index);
    int cod();


};

int sir::cod()
    {
        sir u=*this;
        char* s=sirul;
        int i,sum,l=lung;
        if (lung=0)
            cout<<"ASCII code sum is 0";
        else
        {
            for(i=0; i<l; i++)
                {
                    sum=sum+int(s[i]);
                }
        }
        return sum;
    }

sir::sir(const char* siroriginal)
{
  int lungime=strlen(siroriginal);//string length
  lung = lungime+1;
  sirul = new char[lung];
  strcpy(sirul,siroriginal);
}

sir::~sir(){
  delete sirul;
}

char sir::operator[](int index){
  if(index<lung && index >=0)return sirul[index];//verificare minima, verific daca este in limite
  return '\0';
}

int main(){



  cout<<"--------------test for sir-----------------\n";
  sir s("un sir meserias");
  char c=s[1];
  cout<<c<<"\n";
    cout<<s.cod();



}
```

When I'm executing this program an error says that "double free or corruption", I don't understand what causes this error. It appears after I'm trying to calculate ASCII code sum of my sir(string) with `cod` method, that should return an integer value.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Try attaching a debugger to your running program, you'll learn a lot! :)

Comment: I don't quite know how to do that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few problems within your code :

**1. First :**

You have a **mismatched** `new[]`/`delete` call here. Replace `delete sirul` by `delete[] sirul`.

**2. Second :**

Inside `sir::cod`, you are actually copying your object by doing

```
sir u=*this;
```

Since you are not using `u` at all, you should remove this line. It is the source of your double free. At the end of the `cod` function, `u` will be destroyed and your internal pointer `sirul` will be deleted. But since you haven't defined any copy operator, the compiler will generate it for you and you'll end up sharing a pointer across two `sir` instances.
When the second instance is destroyed, `sirul` is deleted again. Resulting in the error.

**3. Third :**

Next, in `cod`, you forgot to initialize `sum` to 0. That's why you have bad results.

**4. Fourth :**

In `cod`, you are doing `if (sum = 0)`. You are missing the `==` here.

Comment: thanks, here it how looks working "cod" now:
int sir::cod()
    {
        int i, sum=0;
        if (lung==0)
            cout<<"Valoarea ASCII este 0";
        else
        {
            for(i=0; i<lung; i++)
                {
                    sum=sum+int(sirul[i]);
                }
        }
        return sum;
    }